# How do I fetch my config json file inside service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, ecmascript-5

I have a firebase configuration file inside my `tools/apache/htdocs/apps/config/firebase-config.json`
I need this config file in my serviceworker `tools/apache/htdocs/firebase-messaging-sw.js`

Is there any way in es5?

Comment: What is the filytype of the config file?

Comment: The file system path is irrelevant. Under what URL is that file accessible from the web?

Comment: Why would you limit yourself to ES5? But that has nothing to do with the available web apis anyway.

Comment: import { config } from '../config.js';

Comment: @aside json file

Comment: @Bergi  well its a https url. consider it to be https://example.com and service worker sits in root directory

Comment: @Nishanth So just use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with the respective path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fetch("./config/firebaseConf.json").then(function (res) {
  return res.json();
}).then(function (data) {
 var firebase =  data;
})
```

The above code worked for me.

Comment: When I do this, Angular is returning the root/SPA html instead of the contents of config.json.